# dockerfile : npm not found at entrypoint?

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I have this dockerfile :

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR .
COPY . /service/api/

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl python3 curl

ENV NODE_VERSION 16.19.1
# install nvm
RUN cd / && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash && cd / && \
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
    cd /service/api/ && rm -rf node_modules && npm install


ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

ADD start.sh /start.sh

#ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
CMD cd /service/api/ && npm start
```

The image compiles correctly but it can't start because 'npm not found'.
When I uncomment the other debug entrypoint above to exec in the container, I see that npm -v and node -v are available in it.

Why aren't they available in my entrypoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RUN ... export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` does not allow you to use `$NVM_DIR` later in the Dockerfile to benefit from Docker variables substitutions. Only variables defined by a line starting with `ENV` can be used later (except when using the variable in a line starting with `RUN`, but this variable replacement is not implemented by Docker but by a shell). Therefore, your Dockerfile line `ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules` does not resolve `$NVM_DIR` to the correct path (`$NVM_DIR` is simply replaced by an empty string, at this step).

Simply add `ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm` just before `ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules` and this will correct your Dockerfile.

The correct Dockerfile should be:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR .
COPY . /service/api/

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl python3 curl

ENV NODE_VERSION 16.19.1
# install nvm
RUN cd / && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash && cd / && \
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
    cd /service/api/ && rm -rf node_modules && npm install


ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

ADD start.sh /start.sh

#ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
CMD cd /service/api/ && npm start
```

Comment: explanations + solution works perfectly thank you! :)